# Find rectangular equation from parametric equation???

Tags: parametric

Find rectangular equation from parametric

$ x = t^{2} + t $

$ y = t^{2} - t $

I tried finding the equation but I am stuck here:

$ x - t^{2} = t $

$ y = t^{2} - t $

$ y = t^{2} - ({x - t^{2}}) $

$ y = t^2 - x + t^2  $

$y = 2t^2 - x $

Is there even a parametric equation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $x-y=2t$, hence $t=(x-y)/2$. Substituting in the first equation gives
$$x=\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2+\frac12(x-y)\iff4x=x^2-2xy+y^2+2x-2y$$ $$\iff x^2-2xy+y^2-2x-2y=0.$$

Comment: Thank you! I was really having trouble with this problem!

Comment: Okay now I have

$ y = x - 2t $

substituting t 

$ y = x - 2(\frac{x-y}{2})$

and finally 

$ y = x - (x - y)$

I end up with no equation ):

Comment: No, you have to substitute $t$ in one of the original equations.

Comment: Okay I did that and I'm stuck at 

$ y = (x-y)^2 - (x-y) $ 
then 
$ y = x^2 - 2xy + y^2 - x + y $ 

I'm mostly lost with (2xy). I do not know how to work with that

Comment: Is the general second degree equation counted as a "rectangular equation"?

Comment: Of course, because it is an equation in rectangular coordinates.  You may feel free to solve it for $y$, but why?

Comment: I (wrongfully) assumed that rectangular coordinates need to match a predefined conic (by my definition, hyperbolas, ellipses and parabolas along the x or y axis).

Comment: It's a parabola, in our case.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x-2t\\
0=t^2+t-x\\
-2t = 1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}\\
y=1+x+\sqrt{1+4x}\\
y=1+x-\sqrt{1+4x}$

Comment: where did u get $2t-1$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $ 2t + 1 $ sorry

Comment: I'll delete that. I just used the quadratic equation.

Comment: Im still very confused with steps 1, 2, 3

Comment: I get 1 just not how you got to 2 and 3

Comment: 2 is just the original equation. Then I used the quadratic equation, solving for t in terms of x

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$x+y=2t^2\iff t^2=\frac{x+y}2, x-y=2t\iff t=\frac{x-y}2$$

$$\implies\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)^2=\frac{x+y}2\iff (x-y)^2=2(x+y)$$

Comment: @SwagmcMuffin, how about this?

Comment: Cool, thanks. Gave me more ideas